# SQL request with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help about liaison between 3 tables.
I would like to inspire of this code in java.

```
ResultSet resu = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().selectQuery (req);
        try {
            while (resu.next())
            {        
                myList.add (new Collabo(resu.getInt("IdOrg"), 
                             new Album(resu.getString("CodeA"), resu.getString("TitreA"), 
                             new Chanteur (resu.getInt("IdentC"),resu.getString("IdentC")),
                             resu.getDate("DateArrivee"))));


             }
        }
```

I just know to join 2 tables for now

```
Select IdOrg, A.CodeA
from collabo A, album C
where A.CodeA = C.CodeA order by 1
```

[image: here is my DB for information]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You haven't shown the definition of your table(s), without which it's hard to give a good answer.  See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Look into ANSI joins. The way you have joined the tables here is old and generally ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT c.IdOrg, a.CodeA, ch.NomC
FROM album a 
LEFT JOIN collabo c ON a.CodeA = c.CodeA
LEFT JOIN chanteur ch ON a.IdentC = ch.IdentC
ORDER BY a.CodeA
```